# How can I select all the li that doesn't have ul

Tags: html, css, html-lists

What I want to do is select `<li>` not having inside `<ul>`.

I tried with the selector above but it does not work.

```css
.level1:not(:has(ul)) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="level1">Link1</li>
  <li class="level1">Link2
    <ul>
      <li>Link2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why not style the `<li>` and override that style if it contains `<ul>`?

Comment: because in my project structure this has to be done

Comment: Yes, thats why you asked. But what is wrong with another approach?

Comment: I dont't have control to change the approach in CSS and it's complicated to change now everything.
I just need to select <li> that does not contain <ul>

Comment: I don't think it can be done without either changing the markup (adding classes) or using JS. CSS does not have a parent selector.

Answer (score 1):

Add another class to `li` that doesn't contain `ul` and then apply css to that class

```css
.some-class {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="level1 some-class">Link1</li>
  <li class="level1">Link2
    <ul>
      <li>Link2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT**

If you can't edit your markup and this is your final markup then you can use `:first-child`or `:first-of-type` something like this

```css
.level1:first-child {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="level1">Link1</li>
  <li class="level1">Link2
    <ul>
      <li>Link2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I would go for this approach too, but OP is suggesting he doesn't have the ability to change, so I can't upvote

Comment: so it's simple but I do not have access to put that class out there ... so you'll need another approach

Comment: @Cristi: I think you need to accept that there isn't another approach, this isn't something you can do with only CSS (not at the moment anyway)

Comment: @Cristi I've updated the answer

Comment: @musefan updated the answer. I've answered in the phone. Later on PC I'll edit the answer with snippets

Comment: @dippas: I suppose technical it does work on the OP requirements now haha. Though I think we both know it was an example, and OP cant rely on it just being the first child